# No thumbnail when sharing a post to facebook

Tags: facebook, image, share, blogger

I'm having a problem since this past week. When I try to share a video from my website (blogger), the youtube thumbnail doesn't appear.

See this example:

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?app_id=309437425817038&sdk=joey&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.antesfossefacil.com%2F2013%2F02%2Fque-puto-de-golaco-dos-melhores-de.html&display=popup

Comment: Isn't this an exact duplicate of your other question (http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/q/15231287/1721527)?

Comment: but they closed the question

Comment: There was a reason your other question was closed, and this one is likely to get closed too. Instead of reposting your question, edit your old one and make it better.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the URL through the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.antesfossefacil.com%252F2013%252F02%252Fque-puto-de-golaco-dos-melhores-de.html), it will show you these warnings for your URL.

> Small og:image:   All the images referenced by og:image should be at
>   least 200px in both dimensions, with 1500x1500 preferred. (Maximum
>   image size is 5MB.) Please check all the images with tag og:image in
>   the given url and ensure that it meets the recommended specification.
>
> og:image should be larger:  Provided og:image is not big enough. Please
>   use an image that's at least 200x200 and preferably 1500x1500.
>   (Maximum image size is 5MB.) Image
>   'http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Cq-6EzxeQ7A/T57exlijroI/AAAAAAAAAqo/X_opAw26xxU/s1600/antesfoss+NOVO+1.png'
>   will be used instead.

Fix these warnings to generate that thumbnail.

Comment: yes, that exactly my problem, but I don't know how to do that

Comment: What you mean? You use a bigger image. You need to use an image with a height and width of >= 200 pixels.

Comment: but the image is from the youtube video, the debugger is getting a default --> http://img.youtube.com/vi/moHR8tzNeyA/default.jpg 

and that image dont have the 200px

Comment: Use the `maxresdefault.jpg` endpoint instead of `default`. So in your example: http://img.youtube.com/vi/moHR8tzNeyA/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: and how do I make blogger to do that?

Comment: Idk, I'm not a blogger expert.